# My .NET CORE application crashes randomly on Ubuntu 18

Tags: .net, linux, ubuntu, crash, nopcommerce

I have an application nopcommerce, in most cases the application can run well, but sometime later, it randomly crashes

This is the syslog for the process:

```
Apr 12 19:35:17 nopvps nopCommerce: #033[40m#033[32minfo#033[39m#033[22m#033[49m: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics
[2]
Apr 12 19:35:17 nopvps nopCommerce:       Request finished in 65.8038ms 302
Apr 12 19:35:17 nopvps nopCommerce: Stack overflow.
Apr 12 19:35:17 nopvps systemd[1]: nopCommerce: Main process exited, code=killed, status=6/ABRT
Apr 12 19:35:17 nopvps systemd[1]: nopCommerce: Failed with result 'signal'.
Apr 12 19:35:27 nopvps systemd[1]: nopCommerce: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Apr 12 19:35:27 nopvps systemd[1]: nopCommerce: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1.
```

Do you have any idea about this issue?